# Android Studio 3.0 + Kotlin Two Gradle Daemon

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

Is it normal for Android Studio 3.0 (Beta 7) to have 2 gradle daemon running when the product is compiled with Java + Kotlin? It's consuming alot of resources just to build a project

[image: System Monitor Screen Shot]

**Update 10/27/17**
I've updated Android Studio 3.0 but getting two Gradle Daemon, I think the other daemon is for Kotlin Compiler as it says `kotlin-compiler-embedabble-1.1.51.jar`. But why does it need to have a separate process...

Comment: Why not update to release? :)

Comment: I'll try to update and post the result. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: for more information can you follow this link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html#known_issues